# Rotating of background image issues

Tags: html, css

I've found [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/)
I have an element with background image. So I want to set background image to `:before` element. But when I try it, there is no background image at all.
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7enerv0/1/) As you can see I set background property:

```
background: #6D7B8F url('http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/16x16-Free-Application-Icons_1.png') -10px -20px no-repeat;
```

And it is fine. But if you comment that css code and uncomment other css (implementation of tutorial) the background dissapears.

Comment: add to div#settings:before  - display: inline-block; or display: block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Following Which you need from given tutorial

```css
#settings {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 5em;
    margin: 3em auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12em;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}



#settings::before {
    background: url("http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/16x16-Free-Application-Icons_1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    height: 200%;
    left: -50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg); 
}
```

```html
<div id="settings">Test</div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/p7enerv0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add [z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), to your :before selector

Answer (score 0):

You code seems just fine. 
You should not use the 'overflow:hidden'  as it seems to hide the background element in your fiddle.

```css
.kitten {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: pink; 
}
.kitten::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9gus8QYjY1rw0ggfo3_r5_400.gif);
  background-size: contain;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kitten"></div>
```